# Howto verify if macro is defined and stop make otherwise?

Tags: gnu-make

Since an undefined variable can lead to an unexpected behavior if it is simply replaced with empty text (consider target directories), is there a way to have make check if a variable is undefined and stop with an error in that case?

The condition can be detected with conditionals but then how to stop execution?

```
ifeq ($(strip $(notdefinedforsure_man)),)
out = Undefined variable detected
endif
```

I'm looking for something like
    requiredef var1, var2

or a simple return with error statement to be used in the conditional above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `origin` builtin function:

```
ifeq (undefined,$(origin VARIABLE))
  $(error VARIABLE is not defined)
endif
```

See [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html) for details.

Comment: Or `$(if $(filter undefined,$(origin VARIABLE)),$(error blurk!))` if you need it inside a macro.